# Vertically center text that has no descenders?

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have a single line of text that is in all caps (e.g. with `text-transform: uppercase`).  I want to center this text vertically in a `div`.  I don't need to worry about multi-line text.

There are several ways to center things vertically in CSS (e.g. check [this](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/) out).  Unfortunately, all these methods take [descenders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender) into account, and my text doesn't have any descenders so it isn't centered perfectly.  Basically, I want to center the portion of the text from the baseline to the cap height.

Is there any way to vertically center a line of capitalized text?  Right now I'm using `position: relative` and manually tweaking it until it is centered (e.g. with `top: 2px`), but this is clearly not a robust solution (it is very dependent on the way the browser renders text, what fonts are available, etc.).  Thanks!

Comment: please post the HTML and CSS

Comment: does it make any difference if you use a font size defined in pixels? and then use the same offset you have but taking into account the max descender height?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to vertically center text in its bounding box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36891362/is-it-possible-to-vertically-center-text-in-its-bounding-box)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some testing, it seems I was wrong about how text is vertically centered.  It turns out that most browsers do exactly what I want—they don't take descenders into account.

For those who were unclear about what I was asking:  The "descender" is the part of text that goes below the baseline.  For example, the lowercase characters "g" and "y" have parts that go  below the baseline.  I wanted to vertically center text that does not have characters like these (in my case, only uppercase characters like "X").

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/fyvyB/2/) is a jsfiddle that demonstrates what I found (which sets `line-height` to the height of the `div`).  Notice that the "X" is centered properly, which makes the "g" overflow outside the div.  But that's okay for me, because the text is all caps.

Comment: It seems to depend on the font. I tried your fiddle solution with different fonts and the cap height was not centered vertically. Your Oswald font happened to be one that worked.

Answer (score 2):

line-height is actually given when we want to align the block elements in between along y-axis.

For example, i have a singled line text in w3schools and para height is 20px. The paragraph will be written in its own default way but if i use line-height equals the height of the paragraph then text in say W3schools will be aligned in the middle along y-axis. While if you want to horizontally align (x-axis align) your text then text-align:center is used for this purpose.

Remember, line-height do not totally depend on the height of its own element height. But it changes as follows.

1. If you have a single line text, height is 20px then give
   line-height: 20px to vertically align the text or vertically middle
   of text.
2. If you have a two line of text, height is 20px then give the line-height:10px and with the small padding-top to vertically align the text.

I hope this will lift you up. And i think you will not need to browse google more. If more you want explanation then i will give you jfiddle code. :)