# Remove added area or height taken up by element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align some text within a border. On inspecting the element which in this case is an `a` tag there is some extra space below the typography itself that is un aligning the text.

How would you remove this?

The issue in question is the blue highlight part of the text below.

[image: Extra space below text]

Here are the current styles:

```css
.creations-link {
  border: 1.75px solid var(--dark);
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 0.3rem 2rem;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: can you create [mre] please with snippet so we can test this with our ownn dev tools and not look at your image please?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this problem but almost `line-height` property may solve the problem.

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16272775/1011984 which recommends specifying the `height` and `line-height` with the same values.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `position:absolute` with `line-height:0` to remove text height
**but...**
most probably extra spaces will be resolved if you just tweak lign-height value;

```css
.creations-link {
  border: 1.75px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 1.0rem 2rem;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 0;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<a class="creations-link"> view all <a>
```